# How do I solve the certificate error in debian. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, curl, ssl-certificate

So I am trying to install React on my computer which runs ChromeOS but I am running debian side by side. When I try to execute the command `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -` then the error `CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none` comes and this error is also shown when I run `sudo apt-get update`. I have tried to do many things but nothing has happened, please help me as this is very important.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu:

- Go to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
- Create a new folder, i.e. "sudo mkdir school"
- Copy the .crt file into the school folder
- Make sure the permissions are OK (755 for the folder, 644 for the file)
- Run "sudo update-ca-certificates"